# Is it possible to install SSMS on an Azure VM and connect to a Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have an Azure SQL Database that I currently connect to from my on-premises laptop computer.  I would like to install SSMS on an Azure Virtual Machine and have my complete stack in the Azure Cloud.  Is it possible to install SSMS (or comparable tool) on an Azure VM and connect to an Azure SQL Database and Azure Data Warehouse?

I looked in the Azure Marketplace and don't see any images for SSMS.  I'm assuming I'm just missing something so I would appreciate it if you can set me straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install SSMS on Azure VM (assuming it is a windows VM or any other OS where you can install SSMS).

An Azure VM is just like any other on-premise VM or Physical machine. In the Azure VM you can do anything that you can do in an on-premise VM or Physical machine.

Just like for your on-premise VM or Physical machine you would also need to create a firewall rule on your SQL Azure DB for your Azure VM before you can connect to the Azure DB from your SSMS in the Azure VM.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm unable to find any SSMS images in the marketplace.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor You can download it from the website [`Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: forgive my ignorance, this is all new to me.  So my steps would be to create a windows VM on Azure.  Use explorer to go to the link you provided download SSMS onto the VM and simply install as if it were on my desktop.    Thaks again for you input.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor absolutely as simple as this.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep the accept answer as the accepted answer.

But I wanted to add that Azure has some 'pre canned' virtual machine images.

For example:

**Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10 Enterprise N**

> Visual Studio Community is our free, full featured and extensible IDE
>   for non-enterprise application development. This image contains the
>   recommended product install of the originally released (or 'RTW')
>   version of Visual Studio Community 2017 on the Windows 10 Enterprise N
>   (version 1809), including the Universal Windows app development tools
>   and the latest Windows 10 SDK. It allows you to quickly setup
>   environment in Azure to develop and test applications targeting the
>   Universal Windows Platform

So (even if I had to manually install SSMS) I might start with one of these pre-canned-VM designed for doing developer work.

So my answer is that you don't have to start with a plain-jane-windows-OS-VM...you might check the market place for something more featured.

Note the above VS version is "community".  Obviously, if you need something more robust, you're gonna have to bring-your-own-license and do a self-install on the VM.